# Integrability of sequence of uniform convergence function defined on unbound domain

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

Consider $(f_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ being a sequence of function defined on interval $(-\infty,0]$. Assume it is uniform convergence to a function $f$. If each $f_{n}$ is Lebesgue integrable, is $f$ integrable and $\int f=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int f_{n}$? Will the result different if $f_{n}$ is Riemann integrable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider for instance the sequence $(f_n)_n$ given by
$$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}
1/(i-1) & \text{if } i-1<x\leq i \text{ for some } i\in\mathbb{N}, i\leq n\\
0 & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}$$
Then this sequence converges uniformly to $$f(x)=1/(i-1) \text{ if }i-1<x\leq i,$$
which is not Lebesgue integrable. This example also works for Riemann integrability.

Answer (score 1):

Define

$$f_n(x)=\frac{1}{1+|x|} \chi_{[-n,0]}(x),\,\, f(x) = \frac{1}{1+|x|}.$$

Then $\sup_{(-\infty,0]} |f-f_n| = \sup_{(-\infty,n]} |f| = 1/(n+1).$ Thus $f_n\to f$ uniformly on $(-\infty,0].$ Each $f_n$ is integrable, but $f$ is not.